# Where is wctype in Visual C 2008 Express?

Tags: visual-c++, widestring

I'm porting 3rd party software from Linux to Windows using Visual C 2008 Express.

I have trouble only with function `wctype'. It's declared in %VCDIR%/include/wctype.h file as follow:

```
 _MRTIMP2 wctype_t __cdecl wctype (const char *);
```

But, when trying to link a have the following error:

```
C:\test>cl test.c
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.30729.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

test.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 9.00.30729.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:test.exe
test.obj
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _wctype referenced in function _main
test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

The test code is following:

```
#include <wctype.h>

int
main (void)
{
  return (int) wctype ("alpha");
}
```

As you can see in error message, code is compiling OK, but cannot link.

What to do? I'm not a developer of this software, so I don't want to replace `wctype' function with another, because it can confuse original developers.

Thanks for patience.

P.S. I've also looked at MSVCRT90.DLL file's import table with Dependency Walker and there are no `wctype' function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`cl test.c  /link MSVCPRT.LIB`

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer.  Linking to libcmt.lib causes horrible problems.

Answer (score 1):

You need to link with libcp.lib as mentioned here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa246681(VS.60).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you use msvcprt.lib you'll have to redistribute a DLL depending on your setup (e.g. MSVCP90.dll). If you don't want to redistribute try this:

```
cl test.c /link libcpmt.lib
```

A list of all the libraries to link to are here (look at the bottom): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx